# Outputing a non-ASCII character using echo in php

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

Consider my following PHP code:

```
$text="আমাদের";
echo $text[0];
```

The word `আমাদের` is a Bengali word. The problem is that, even each of the characters in the string has no ASCII value, the code `ord($text[0])` outputs a number. Moreover, the above program outputs a non sense character while it should show the first character in the string `$text`, that's what the index 0 means. I am showing my output in a HTML page that has UTF-8 encoding set as `<meta charset='UTF-8'>`.
The question is why I am not getting the desired output, which is the first character 'অ', rather, a non-sense character.

Comment: Why not try [mb_substr()](https://3v4l.org/5XQNk)? I get 'আ'. I do notice a difference with your character, but I don't know enough about Bengali to know if that is significant. PHP supports multi-byte characters with [Multibyte String Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php).

Comment: *"that's what the index 0 means"* No, index 0 means "first byte".